# How to call an InlineKeyboardButton by id anytime the button is pressed

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

I am trying to write a python telegram bot that works like a betting platform. It has a list of matches and I want that anytime a match is selected from that list, it calls the match option by id and then call the bet function of that match then the user has to select which team he wish to bet on. Then when he clicks on a team it increments the jackpot of that match the display the total. if another match is selected, it does the same for that match

This is my code. I wanted that when any of those three match button are  pressed, it shows another option below for the user to select his team to bet on and the increment the jackpot. But it when you run the program it does it only for one match

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

from .serializers import BetSerializer
from api.models import Bets   
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types


from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton


import telegram

keyboard_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
kb_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Team 1", callback_data="team_1")
button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Team 2", callback_data="team_2")
button3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="result", callback_data="result")
button4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="FCB vs PSG", callback_data="bet_1")
button5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="RMD vs MCI", callback_data="bet_2")
button6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="CMR vs BRS", callback_data="bet_3")
keyboard_inline.add(button1, button2)
keyboard_inline.add(button3)
kb_inline.add(button4)
kb_inline.add(button5)
kb_inline.add(button6)



bot = Bot(token='TOKEN')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Hello! Im Lele bot, Please follow the instruction")
    


@dp.message_handler(commands=['bet'])
async def option(message):
    global a, b
    a = 0
    b = 0
    await message.reply("Select a team:", reply_markup=kb_inline)
    # await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Team 1 - " + str(a) + " FCFA\nTeam 2 - " + str(b) +" FCFA")


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: True)
async def choice(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    global a, b
    if call.data == "bet_1":
        
        await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Select a team:", reply_markup=keyboard_inline)
    if call.data == "team_1":
        a += 100
        await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Team 1 - " + str(a) + " FCFA\nTeam 2 - " + str(b) +" FCFA")
    elif call.data == "team_2":
        b += 100
        await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Team 1 - " + str(a) + " FCFA\nTeam 2 - " + str(b) +" FCFA")
    elif call.data == "result":
        sum = a + b
        print(sum)
        await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "---CAGNOTTE---\n"
                                                     "Total = " + str(sum) + " fCFA")
        a = b = 0
        
    await call.answer()

executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be to any button add callback filter:

```
from aiogram.utils.callback_data import CallbackData

cb_inline = CallbackData("post", 'action', "data")
keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
    inline_keyboard= [
        InlineKeyboardButton(text='MyText', callback_data=cb_inline.new(action='myact', data='MyText')
        ]
    )

@dp.callback_query_handler(cb_inline.filter(action='myact'))
async def choice_registr_method(call: CallbackQuery, callback_data):
    pass
```

Comment: please what does this do ?

Comment: Can you please explain how i can adapt it to my program and what can be the result

Comment: On button set "action" and "text". In handler set filter to action name. If user tap to button, request go to handler with it`s "action" and "text" in callback_data["data"]